# MySQL status_id changed over time select just the latest based on the needed status

Tags: mysql

I know this sounds a little bit strange but I don't really know how to explain this better without an example.

I have the following table

```
ID contract_id status_id created
1  1           1        2015-10-14
2  1           2        2015-10-15
3  1           1        2016-02-02
4  1           4        2017-03-01
```

If the query is something like
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status_id = 1 AND created BETWEEN 2015-10-10 AND 2017-03-05
The item with contract_id = 1 should not display because the latest status in that date interval is 4 
But if the query is something like this 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status_id = 1 AND created BETWEEN 2015-10-10 AND 2017-02-28 the item with contract_id 1 should show up because the latest status_id = 1

Basically what I need is something like this: Get me the latest item if the status_id = 1 at the end date

I know this is quite simple but I running around in circles right now. I did try abs(datediff(end, start)), select based on if or select in select but I am not getting the result I am looking for.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I read this explanation 3 times and still can't understand it.
Do you mean that you want to see a result only if the status is not larger than the specified status?

Comment: For e.g.: on the end date = 2017-02-28 the latest status close to this date is 1 so this row should be in the result set but if the end date = 2017-03-05 the row should not show since the closest status_id = 4, did this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approaches would be to use an INNER JOIN of the latest date a given contract_id had the required status, and test if the date is earlier than the border date:

EDIT: After further reading the comments, most probably this one will do exactly what you need

```
SELECT t.*
FROM statuses AS t 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(id) AS lastid, max(created) AS lastdate
    FROM statuses
    WHERE status_id = 1 AND created < '2016-01-01'
    GROUP BY contract_id 
    ) AS latest ON t.ID = latest.lastid
```

Note that it will work only if the dates are put in chronologically, in other words that for every contract_id:   ID' < ID''   ≡   created' < created''

Comment: I did run this query
`SELECT *
FROM contract_histories AS t 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(id) AS lastid, max(created) AS lastdate
    FROM contract_histories
    WHERE status_id = 1
    GROUP BY contract_id 
    ) AS latest ON t.ID = latest.lastid AND latest.lastdate < '2017-03-30' `


But for e.g. it did return contract_id 1 that had it's last status_id = 3
It dosen't really work, but I do think this will help me

Comment: Maybe there is still a bit of a misunderstanding :) In the inside query I'm finding the latest example when the given contract_id had the required status. And then I'm finding if that latest example falls before the border date or not.  Most probably you would want what I put after an edit.

Comment: contract_id: ID` == ID'' but created' < created'' (created is used for each insert).
This is a history table for the contract so every time the contract has a new status the created will be the current date of the edit but a contract can have multiple edits for specific statuses, not to mention it could have something like this (in it's history) Status_id: 1,2,3,4,6,1,4,5 on different dates and I am interested if the contract has the status_id: 1 as the latest status in the given interval(the end date is more important then the interval) I use the interval in order not to select all the items

Comment: I don't understand "contract_id: ID` == ID'' but created' < created'' ".
ID is the unique ID of the record as I understand it, so how come ID` == ID''?  My expression is precise: for every contract_id, a higher date means a higher ID and vice versa, which you seem to confirm, that the status changes are recorded chronologically.  Does the second query do whart you want?

Comment: I thought you refer to the ID` as the contract_id not the actual ID. In fact the inner join will return all the contracts because at some point in time for e.g. all contracts have the status_id = 1. I am trying now to do an other join or cross join to see if that works

Comment: I removed my first proposal, and left only the second one, which I think will do what you require. Did you try it?

Comment: Stan, thank you very much for you effort but this is not working as intended. I am going to accept the answer anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status_id = 1 AND created BETWEEN 2015-10-10 AND 2017-03-05 AND ROWNUM <=1 ORDER BY created desc
```

MySQL :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status_id = 1 AND created BETWEEN 2015-10-10 AND 2017-03-05 ORDER BY created desc LIMIT 1
```

SQL Server :

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM table WHERE status_id = 1 AND created BETWEEN 2015-10-10 AND 2017-03-05 ORDER BY created desc
```

I understood your question as that you want an item with status_id = 1 and which has most recent created date

Comment: Yes but there are multiple items so I cannot limit to 1. I need to select all items from the DB that have the status_id = 1 closest to the end date.